Images in /dist folder don't load on page (Parcel + Gulp)
click to see the issue image
I have my gulpfile.js configured:
import gulp from 'gulp';
import { plugins } from './config/gulp-plugins.js';
import { path } from './config/gulp-settings.js';

import { html } from './config/gulp-tasks/html.js';
import { styles } from './config/gulp-tasks/styles.js';
import { serve } from './config/gulp-tasks/_serve.js';

global.app = {
  gulp: gulp,
  path: path,
  plugins: plugins,
};

const devTasks = gulp.series(html, styles, serve);

const buildTasks = gulp.series(html, styles);

const dev = gulp.series(devTasks);

let build = gulp.series(buildTasks);

export { dev };
export { build };

Eveything goes to /dist folder, including images and fonts i have in ./src/assets/images and ./src/assets/fonts.
I am using posthml-include to seperate and include later html files.
The problem is that my website loads, but instead of images I see their alt (alternative) text, no matter what I do. The path to them is set correct. But in ./dist/index.html they don't show.
THEY ONLY SHOW IF USE INCLUDE FOR THEM TOO, BUT THIS WAY I AM NOT USING NATIVE HTML IMG TAG.
I want the browser to load images from dist folder in my ./dist/index.html
